# Need to optimize my mathematical py code with lists

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Im not very sure if I will translate the assignment correctly, but the bottom line is that I need to consider the function `f(i) = min dist(i, S)`, where S is number set of length k and `dist(i, S) = sum(j <= S)(a (index i) - a(index j))`, where a integer array.
I wrote the following code to accomplish this task:

```
n, k = (map(int, input().split()))
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
sorted_arr = arr.copy()
sorted_arr.sort()
dists = []
returned = []
ss = 0
indexed = []
pop1 = None
pop2 = None
for i in arr:
    index = sorted_arr.index(i)
    index += indexed.count(i)
    indexed.append(i)
    dists = []
    if (index == 0):
        ss = sorted_arr[1:k+1]
    elif (index == len(arr) - 1):
        sorted_arr.reverse()
        ss = sorted_arr[1:k+1]
    else:
        if index - k < 0:
            pop1 = 0
        elif index + k > n - 1:
            pop2 = None
        else: 
            pop1 = index - k
            pop2 = index + k + 1
        ss = sorted_arr[pop1:index] + sorted_arr[index + 1: pop2]
    for ind in ss:
        dists.append(int(abs(i - ind)))
        dists.sort()
    returned.append(str(sum(dists[:k])))
print(" ".join(returned))
```

But I need to speed up its execution time significantly.

Comment: There is no function `f` defined in your code, at all!! You need to use keyword `def` to define a function.

Comment: We are talking about a mathematical function. I don't use def as it slows down the code